# ExtJS4, How to prevent sending request every time user type text

Tags: combobox, extjs4

I have simple combo with remote store. `pagination`, `triggerAction` doesn't matter for me.
All I need is disable sending request everytime I type smth in combo.
[image]

Even when I have `triggerAction: 'all'` request are being sent.
How can I disable it? I need to load store just one time. Please help me!

Comment: In future you should at least provide the code for the combo box, no code makes it difficult to diagnose in most cases.

Comment: I'm sorry. My bad. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `queryMode: 'local'`.

Docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-queryMode).

Comment: that helped me. But also I need to specify when to load that store. Depends on situation. Thanks for help